# Why does merging data.tables not work for long numeric keys in R, and ways to avoid?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am working with a dataset that has some fairly absurdly long IDs. After not getting the result I expected, I traced the issue to a step of code where I merged two data tables.

Example:

```
options("scipen" = 999) ## The only way I know to disable scientific notation.
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.table("ID" = sample(400000000000:400000000004, size = 5), 
                     "colA" = rep('a', 5))
table2 <- data.table("ID" = sample(400000000000:400000000001, size = 2), 
                     "colB" = rep('b', 2))
merge(table1, table2, by = "ID", all.x = F)
```

Since each ID is unique in each table, I would expect the output to be two rows long (returning only the matching rows of `table2` due to `all.x = F`).

Instead, I get:

```
             ID colA colB
1: 400000000000    a    b
2: 400000000000    a    b
3: 400000000001    a    b
4: 400000000001    a    b
```

At a certain point, it looks like R stops reading these integers as distinct for calculation purposes. It looks like `right_join()` in `dplyr` doesn't have this particular problem, and in this case it's not crucial by any means for me to keep the `data.table` class... but I'd still be interested in knowing if it's avoidable and why this limitation pops up (and why `join()` avoids it).

Comment: The join works for me - using `data.table v1.9.7 (dev version)`

Comment: Fyi, those are not ints. Try `str(table1)`. If you want long ints, I think the package recommends int64

Comment: From technical point of view join on double data type doesn't make sense, as this is floating precision number and depends on architecture, in such case I would use appropriate data type, which is `integer64` from `bit64` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `merge` documentation :

> Merges on numeric columns: Columns of numeric types (i.e., double)
>   have their **last two bytes rounded off** while computing order, by
>   defalult, to avoid any unexpected behaviour due to limitations in
>   representing floating point numbers precisely. For large numbers
>   (integers > 2^31), we recommend using bit64::integer64. Have a look at
>   setNumericRounding to learn more.

The solution here is to use

```
setNumericRounding(0)
merge(table1, table2, by = "ID", all.x = F)
             ID colA colB
1: 400000000000    a    b
2: 400000000001    a    b
```

Comment: Brilliant. Is it good practice to then change `setNumericRounding()` back to some default? What would that be, if so?

Comment: And as far as the warning about 'representing floating point numbers precisely,' should that be concerning for these purposes?

Comment: restore default with `setNumericRounding(2)`